# MongoDB Sharding by foreign key

Tags: mongodb, sharding, database-normalization

Let's say I have two collections: `users` and `items`, where every item belongs to one user:

```
users:
{ id: 1, country: "US" },
{ id: 2, country: "UK" }
```

```
items:
{ id: 123, userId: 1 },
{ id: 456, userId: 2 }
```

I want to separate the documents from these two collections into different regions by using the `user.country` key to separate the data into shards. However I also want to store the items of every user in the same region. Embedding the items into the user document is not feasible for my use-case.

I could attach a `country` attribute to every item and manually keep it up to date, but would much rather avoid that and somehow tell MongoDB to access the country of the associated user.

Is there any way of sharding the `items` collection based on the `country` of it's user?

Comment: No, this is not possible. Using `country` would be a poor sharding key anyway, I assume.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit could you please elaborate on why `country` would be a poor choice? For context: my goal is to separate the data by location, similarly to how it's done in this MongoDB guide https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/sharding-segmenting-data-by-location/

Comment: Please ask a new (researched non-duplicate) question in a new post, not in a comment.

Comment: How many countries do you have? Maybe 10 or 20? And how many shards do you have? It might be difficult to get an even distribution if you have only a couple of values.